# Matching a route with a "file path"

Tags: 8, files, routes

I'm trying to debug a route that should work like the one(s) used by the private: file scheme (i.e., a path like system/files/path/to/file, where path/to/file is an arbitrary string that *may contain '/' characters*).  I more or less copied the the router definition.  For private files:

```
system.private_file_download:
  path: '/system/files/{filepath}'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\system\FileDownloadController::download'
  requirements:
    # Permissive regex to allow slashes in filepath see
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html
    filepath: .+
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

For my "knock-off", which uses a custom scheme called 'session:':

```
file_example.files.session:
  path: '/example/file_example/files/{filepath}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\system\FileDownloadController::download'
    scheme: session
  requirements:
    # Permissive regex to allow slashes in filepath see
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html
    filepath: .+
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

As near as I can tell, my route is never matched; yet the private: case works. What's different here?  How can I debug how the router makes its decisions?

Part of what I need to know is just what route got picked when the private: scheme actually works.  So it would be handy to get a link to the current route. This is a fairly obvious thing to do, but I can't find a reference in the docs.  How can I determine what the "current route" is for current request?

Answer (score 4):

This is a case where reading the routing file is a bit deceptive.

There are actually two similar routes defined in system.routing.yml:

```
system.files:
  path: '/system/files/{scheme}'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\system\FileDownloadController::download'
    scheme: private
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'

system.private_file_download:
  path: '/system/files/{filepath}'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\system\FileDownloadController::download'
  requirements:
    # Permissive regex to allow slashes in filepath see
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html
    filepath: .+
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

After watching in the debugger, it turns out that the matched route is actually `system.files`, and *not* `system.private_file_download`.  But it will not match a tailed-URL at all without help.

The help needed is a "path processor", which is a routine that the router calls to let code do unusual things with route matching.  Here's the one that's used for private: and temporary: files, among other users in Core:

*In core/modules/system/src/PathProcessor/PathProcessorFiles.php:*

```
class PathProcessorFiles implements InboundPathProcessorInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function processInbound($path, Request $request) {
    if (strpos($path, '/system/files/') === 0 && !$request->query->has('file')) {
      $file_path = preg_replace('|^\/system\/files\/|', '', $path);
      $request->query->set('file', $file_path);
      return '/system/files';
    }
    return $path;
  }

}
```

A path processor is a service, and needs a "tagged" service definition.  Here's the one for Core's path processor for the `/system/files` subpath:

*In system.services.yml:*

```
  path_processor.files:
    class: Drupal\system\PathProcessor\PathProcessorFiles
    tags:
      - { name: path_processor_inbound, priority: 200 }
```

Once I'd added the correct route and service definitions, my custom URL scheme works the same way the Core file scheme URLs work.